# How to keep input field placeholder value even after its value is typed in (field has no label)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep the input field placeholder and it works when in focus, but when the input contains a value the placeholder disappears. Any idea how to make this?

[image]

[Fiddle :](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/dvfoju1c/)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Input some text">
```

**Style sheet**

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1
    padding:3px;
}

input{
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #1b1a1a;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve your requirements with a mere placeholder text. The browser will hide the placeholder text by design and there is nothing you can do about it.

I have forked your fiddle suggesting an alternate solution using label element and some simple CSS to achieve the same results without the placeholder.

https://jsfiddle.net/AshwinPrabhuB/u9kjdgfL/

```
input
{
  border: 1px solid #1b1a1a;
    width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input + label
{ 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 18px; 
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 0.9em;
 }

 input:focus + label
 {
   right: 100px;
   display: block;
   top: 5px;
 }

 input:valid+ label
 {
  top: 5px;
 }

<input id="ip" type="text" placeholder="" required="">
<label for="ip">Input some text</label>
```

Comment: forked link please

Comment: @Firefog Done, please refresh the page.

Comment: its overlap input data when not focusing

Comment: okay, that part is tricky. I have edited the fiddle slightly to set it right, but I am not sure of browser support - have not verified